# typescript enforcing HTML elements on props function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

consider the code below:

```
interface ILink {
    clicked: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
    Icon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, 'svg'>>;
    children: string;
    className: string;
    color: string;
}

const Link: React.FC<ILink> = ({
    Icon,
    children,
    color,
    clicked,
    className
}) => {
    const colorClass: React.CSSProperties = { color };

    return (
        <div onClick={clicked} className={className}>
            <Icon style={colorClass} />
            <p style={colorClass}>{children}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

const Navbar: React.FC<INavbar> = ({ setPage }) => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<string>('home');

    const handleClick = (menuItem: string) => {
        setPage(menuItem);
        setIsActive(menuItem);
    };

    return (
        <nav className='sidebarOptions'>
            <section>
                <Link
                    className='sidebarLink logo'
                    Icon={GamesIcon}
                    color={isActive === 'home' ? 'white' : 'grey'}
                    clicked={() => handleClick('home')}>
                    Better Games
                </Link>

             // ... more code
            
          </section>
        </nav>
    );
};
```

my problem is with 'clicked' type on `ILink` interface, especifically.

the principle of typescript is to define a type to a thing (a property in my case) that i am going to use, but if i try to specify the property 'clicked' as it is: `() => (menuItem: string) => void`, it throws a compile time error, but if specify 'clicked' as the description of `onClick` it works.

please, I need explanations regarding that or if you have links from articles, courses or whatever I can find to learn better about that, please, insert in.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Link` component doesn't actually use the value of `menuItem` so it doesn't need to be aware of it.

When you call a function from `onClick` on a `div`, it gets one argument which is the event.  The type which you copied, `React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>`, is the very specific event type for a click action in react on a `div` element.

But you don't need to worry about the event type at all because you aren't using the event.  An `onClick` function is either a function of the event: `(e: Event) => {...}` or it's a function which takes no arguments: `() => {...}`.  In your case you are not using any arguments, so the type which you want for `clicked` in `interface ILink` is `() => void`, which means: a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing.

You might be thinking "it does take an argument, it takes `menuItem`", but you've already dealt with that in the `handleClick` function of `Navbar`.  The `Link` component receives a function which already has the knowledge of the menu item included in it.  This function: `() => handleClick("home")` takes no arguments.

So in summary you have set up everything correctly and you don't need to change anything.  But if you wanted to simplify `ILink`, this will work:

```
interface ILink {
  clicked: () => void;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code function clicked have input event is React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent> but in your function, you pass string value so I think just change in your interface

```
interface ILink {
    clicked: (event: string) => void;
    Icon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, 'svg'>>;
    children: string;
    className: string;
    color: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you 2 step only

1. Make `clicked` type become `(value: string) => void`
2. You can use clicked like this

```js
    <Link
          className='sidebarLink logo'
          Icon={GamesIcon}
          color={isActive === 'home' ? 'white' : 'grey'}
          clicked={handleClick('home')}>
          Better Games
    </Link>
```

This approach is easier because you don't do anything from `event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>`